# How to add background image in my theme which uses color module?

Tags: 7, theming

In my theme i want to add background image instead of background color provide by the color module.

i don't want the background color set by color module instead i want to add background image, is there is any way to do this?, please suggest me.

Comment: Do you know how to edit CSS?  You can simply change the relevant CSS for the background...

Comment: Hi patrick,color module will rewrite the css file, i want to add background image instead of background color